# store dict int value in dict python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that extracted in json format from an API, then trying to iterate into that dictionary, I created an empty dict to store just the value of the key called totalCount, which is an int, then applying a condition to get the value if the key matches with the one I'm interested in, but getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

[image]

[image]

How could I store that int 905 in the dict totalCount so I get dict like this one:

```
totalCount = {'#Items':905}
```

Comment: The argument to `dict.update` should be ["either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs"](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)

Comment: `totalCount.update({v: 905})`?